# can't finish my interviewer task on time

Tags: interviewing

I have an interview for a company that works in software developing and I got a lot of interviews the last one the interviewer give me a 3days to make a small project with technologies that I didn't work with it at all and I didn't know anything about it 
so I start with the project but I can't finish it (50% of it)
so my question how is the interviewer merge if I will be hired or not?
and if I have  a lot of abstraction in personal can I make an excuse and tell him that  and what is the appropriate behave I have to do
Thanks

Comment: We can't answer that. It depends on how well or poorly other applicants did on the same assignment. However, this does strongly suggest that you are not what they are looking for, unless they were deliberately stress-testing by assigning an unreasonable task. It's probably safest to simply assume you won't get this job.

Comment: A half-finished attempt is still worth submitting.  Hell, I got through my first two years at university just with half-finished attempts.  They might not actually expect you to completely finish it and just want to see how far you got.  But no, making up an excuse for why you didn't finish your homework isn't going to fly in a professional environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference, if you do not know the specific technology or toolset that the interviewer asks you to use, make that clear upfront. Ask them if it would be okay to use a different technology (that you are comfortable with) to solve the problem.

This serves two purposes:

1. If the interviewer is not particular about the technology but is interested more in your approach (such as the algorithms you use), you get to present your skills in the best light.
2. If they insist on using the specific technology, then you know that job is not right for you, so you can avoid doing the assignment altogether, and save everyone's time.

Also, if you estimate that you cannot finish the task in the stipulated time, ask them for a time extension before (or soon after) you start the task, with a suitable *genuine* reason. (For example, you are too busy at your *current* job.) Asking for a time extension when the time is about to run out does not look good on you, especially in senior roles where estimating task completion times is an important part of your job.

To share a personal anecdote, I had once interviewed with a company that predominantly worked with C++, so their task description had a lot of C++ references (no pun intended): "Use STL algorithms where necessary", etc. I asked them if a Java solution would do (since they said the task was to test the candidate's OOP skills) and they said the language didn't really matter, and they were happy with my solution.

I also asked them for a time extension a couple of hours after I read the problem because I knew I had to work the coming weekend for a high priority customer delivery. They were cool with that as well, since I did not wait until the last minute to announce, "Sorry, not there yet, can I get 3 more days?"

I made it past the next couple of rounds, but then backed off as I got another job offer by then.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment 
for the  record I am fresh graduated and I was applied for C# 
and the task they ask me it's angular app with bootstrap framework 
and I don't have a clue about any of them and when I asked them to use another language like asp the didn't agree 
so it was so hard for me to build this app in 3 days

Comment: I find it strange that you applied for X and they asked you to use Y. If that happens in future, get that clarified upfront. It could have been a software goofup at their end, which sent your application to the wrong team, or something of that sort.